# passing user from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

**Servlet Class : HelloWorld.java**

```
package org.baba.prakash;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet { 
  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
  {
      response.setContentType("text/html"); 
      PrintWriter out=response.getWriter(); 
      String username=request.getParameter("username"); 
      String password=request.getParameter("password"); 
      out.println(username); 
      out.println("<br>"); 
      out.println(password); 
  }  
}
```

**JSP : order.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
<title>Insert title here</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form method="GET" action="HelloWorld"> 
User Name:<input type="text" name="username"><br> 
Pass Word:<input type="text" name="password"><br> 
<input align="middle" type="submit" value="Submit Form"> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```html
<servlet> 
<description></description> 
<display-name>HelloWorld</display-name> 
<servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>org.baba.prakash.HelloWorld</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Project structure**

Capacitr_mgnt-------->java Resoureces--------->src------>package>Helloworld.java
Capacitr_mgnt----->webcontent--->order.jsp file

error
type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class org.baba.prakash.HelloWorld

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class org.baba.prakash.HelloWorld.HelloWorld

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**Exception Trace:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.baba.prakash.HelloWorld.HelloWorld
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Root Cause:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.baba.prakash.HelloWorld.HelloWorld
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler clearly tells,

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.baba.prakash.HelloWorld.HelloWorld

class `HelloWorld` is not found in the `org.baba.prakash.HelloWorld` path

In your project structure you don't have any package named `org.baba.prakash.HelloWorld`. So create a package named as in the `web.xml` under the `src`.

Comment: package is org.baba.prakash 
i created HelloWorld servlet under this package SO in <servlet-class>org.baba.prakash.HelloWorld</servlet-class> 

Jsp order.jsp is data to servlet 


then why this error is comming or i have create a class instead of servlet

Answer (score 0):

Check if the HelloWorld.class is present in the deployed war WEB-INF/classes folder or if you have a a java project that contains the HelloWorld.java file then whether it is converted into a jar and is present in the WEB-INF/lib folder.